# How to cast JSONSerialization result to an [[String:Any]] data structure?

Tags: ios, json, swift

For my question I have prepared [a simple Playground at Github](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/tree/master/JsonPlayground.playground):

[image: Xcode screenshot]

Parsing a String to JSON works ok with the code:

```
import UIKit

var str =
"""
{"data": [{"uid":9844,"elo":2900,"motto":null,"given":"Ольга","avg_time":"04:13","avg_score":20.5},{"uid":13480,"elo":2875,"motto":null,"given":"Наталья","avg_time":"03:27","avg_score":21.0},{"uid":14376,"elo":2825,"motto":null,"given":"Дмитрий","avg_time":"04:51","avg_score":19.8},{"uid":8458,"elo":2734,"motto":null,"given":"Аля","avg_time":"03:03","avg_score":21.1},{"uid":18384,"elo":2723,"motto":null,"given":"Светлана","avg_time":"02:25","avg_score":19.6},{"uid":18125,"elo":2720,"motto":null,"given":"Людмила","avg_time":"03:57","avg_score":20.2},{"uid":14382,"elo":2708,"motto":null,"given":"Виктория","avg_time":"03:33","avg_score":19.1},{"uid":8380,"elo":2687,"motto":null,"given":"Ihor","avg_time":"01:44","avg_score":18.8},{"uid":15917,"elo":2681,"motto":null,"given":"Наталья","avg_time":"04:53","avg_score":20.1},{"uid":19650,"elo":2673,"motto":"Ты не проиграл, пока не сдался.","given":"Елена","avg_time":"01:46","avg_score":18.0},{"uid":13797,"elo":2653,"motto":null,"given":"Irina","avg_time":"03:27","avg_score":19.5},{"uid":13014,"elo":2648,"motto":null,"given":"Светлана","avg_time":"05:32","avg_score":21.6},{"uid":18811,"elo":2634,"motto":null,"given":"Алеся","avg_time":"03:45","avg_score":19.1},{"uid":13455,"elo":2630,"motto":null,"given":"Татьяна","avg_time":"02:43","avg_score":18.1},{"uid":16783,"elo":2614,"motto":null,"given":"Татьяна","avg_time":"02:28","avg_score":18.3}]}
"""

guard let data = str.data(using: .utf8),
      let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    else { fatalError("Error") }
print(json)
```

but how can I take the list of the objects referenced by the "data" attribute and cast it to a `[[String:Any]]` data structure?

I need it for the later [NSBatchInsertRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsbatchinsertrequest) call.

I have tried `print(json["data"] as? [[String:Any]])` and also `let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:[[String:Any]]]` but get syntax errors:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Unrelated but you can get rid of the `fatalError` – which will never occur by the way – by writing  `let data = Data(str.utf8)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

```
print(json["data"] as? [[String:Any]])
```

> > you can subscript json as it's of type `Any`

Option 1

```
    guard let data = str.data(using: .utf8),
          let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:Any]
        else { fatalError("Error") }
     
    print(json["data"] as? [[String:Any]])
```

Option 2

```
 guard let data = str.data(using: .utf8),
       let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:[[String:Any]]]

       else { fatalError("Error") }

       print(json["data"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Casting your data like this. The root is your one dictionary so, and your data is the value of the data key, which is an array. so you can use it like this.

```
    guard let data = str.data(using: .utf8)
        else { fatalError("Error") }
        
        do {
            let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
            guard let dictData = json as? [String: Any],
                  let resultData = dictData["data"] as? [[String: Any]] else  {
                return
            }
            
            print(resultData)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
```